# ¿Como saber la cardinalidad de una matriz en c++?

Tags: c++, matrices

Me pregunto si alguien me podría ayudar a saber como seria un codigo para saber la cardinalidad de una matriz en c++.

Comment: Muestra algo que hayas intentado para poder ayudarte. El objetivo del sitio es dar sugerencias a problemas puntuales.

Comment: segun wikipedia  La cardinalidad de un conjunto también se suele llamar su tamaño, cuando no existe confusión con otras nociones de tamaño. Es a eso a lo q te refieres?

Comment: No se me dan bien las matrices, pero creo que para saber la cardinalidad de una matriz, [hay que calcularla](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cardinalidad).

Comment: https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=18&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwjzp6zrlN_dAhXHoFMKHTEXAmAQFjARegQIAxAC&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.u-cursos.cl%2Fusuario%2Fab2121f11709dab766d730a39de459de%2Fmi_blog%2Fr%2FCardinalidad.pdf&usg=AOvVaw0oqE6Ln5aUkkPmPhkl-X10

Comment: mira a ver si eso te ayuda